# Callback function to _.each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am trying to generate dynamic content to my HTML using underscore's templating feature. The code is the following:

```
<div id="accordeonExaminadorBaliza" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
  <legend>Examinador de Baliza</legend>
  <ul id="listExaminadorBaliza" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <%  _.each(c.getExaminadores(), function(examinador){ %>
      <li><img width = '80' height = '80' src= "data:image/jpeg;base64,<%= examinador.fotografia %>"> <%= examinador.nome %></li>
    <%  }); %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now, I need to capture the object pertaining the 'li' element the user clicks on it. How can I implement an event listener that on click can capture the object 'examinador' of the current 'li' element? I don't have much experience with javascript, so bear with me.

Comment: hi, in fact I'm trying to use .on() function from jquery to capture the clicked object. I was trying something like: $('#listExaminadorBaliza').on('click', 'li', function(){
                        alert($(this).nome);
                    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identifier `examinador.nome` is used by the templating engine; it is not accessible to scripts running on the page after the text has been written out by the templating engine. Instead, you can have your templating code write out any data you need as `data-` attribute strings on the element (using `-` to output an HTML-escaped value):

```
<%  _.each(c.getExaminadores(), function(examinador){ %>
  <li data-nome="<%- examinador.nome %>"><img width='80' height='80' src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%= examinador.fotografia %>"><%- examinador.nome %></li>
<%  }); %>
```

Then access it with jQuery's `.data`:

```
$('#listExaminadorBaliza').on('click', 'li', function(){
    alert($(this).data("nome"));
    // or
    alert($(this).attr("data-nome"));
});
```

Comment: (1) Why are you using `escape`? That's deprecated because it is broken for non-ASCII data and it is mean to URL-encode things, not HTML-encode them. (2) Why are you expecting `<% x %>` to leave anything in the HTML?

Comment: @muistooshort (1) Because... I've completely forgotten what `escape` does? I've added a reference to HTML escaping. (2) It seems I've forgotten my `=`; I've added it.

Comment: @XVirtusX I omitted an equals sign, so the value was not being written to the HTML by the templating engine. The revised solution may be more helpful.

Comment: From the fine manual: ["If you wish to interpolate a value, and have it be HTML-escaped, use `<%- … %>`"](http://underscorejs.org/#template).

Comment: it is correct, just a minor error. The 'data-nome' attribute has to be set on the li tag and not the img tag.

Comment: That's why we're here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<li data-id="<%= examinador.id %>" onClick="alert(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id'))"><img width = '80' ...
```

You can put a more sophisticated function in the `onClick`, this is just an example

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jgy7nf3t/1/)

Comment: I tried to use something like:
 $('#listExaminadorBaliza li').on('click', function(e){
                        alert(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('nome'));
                    });

but the result is null

Comment: With jQuery try $(e.currentTarget).attr('nome'). Where did you put the `nome` attribute?

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE The `nome` attribute (and `examinador` overall) is used by the templating engine in rendering the HTML; it's not available to the script running on the rendered page.

Comment: its an attribute of the 'examinador' object. It works to generate my 'li', but when I try to alert like you said I get an 'undefined':

$('#listExaminadorBaliza li').on('click', function(e){
                        alert($(e.currentTarget).attr('nome'));
                    });

Comment: @XVirtusX What I mean is did you add the following: <li nome="<%= examinador.nome%>" ... ?

Comment: @XVirtusX I have added a fiddle for this.